# Showing the home page first in Google search results for searches for the domain name

Tags: seo, google-search, google-ranking, homepage

I have `example.com` built in WordPress, SEO done using YOAST, if you search "website.com" for it on Bing or Yahoo or DuckDuckGo, then it will appear on top, followed by `example.com/page` … and that's what the client wants.

The homepage or landing page is called "Profile".

If you search on Google, then `example.com/page` appears first, part of the reason is because it has much more content than the homepage, followed by `example.com`.

The client keeps asking me about it, I told him let it go, you're lucky enough that it's appearing on Google, but he keeps insisting that he wants to sort it, homepage first, followed by whatever page.

He keeps telling me that all his friends, have websites and if you Google for them, they'll be sorted, homepage first and so on. I think the reason is, his friends' websites don't have SEO at all.

What I could do, is turn off any kind of SEO, then Google will show his domain first, or I could turn off indexing for the media in Yoast, then `example.com/page` won't have any leverage over homepage but either of those options would hurt him badly, even if he doesn't know it, because he has many images so indexing media is a huge plus for him.

I could change the title of the homepage from "profile" to "homepage", but I don't know if that would mean anything to Google. Please note that all of the website is made of WordPress pages, it's a portfolio static website.

Is there a way, either by code, or by WordPress plugin or Yoast or Google Webmaster Tool, or sitemap, to get Google to recognize what page is the homepage and get it to show it first hopefully?

Comment: Does your home page title have the website name in it?    Is it literally just "Profile" or is it "Profile -- website.com" or something similar?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller literally  "Profile"  http://lacearchitects.com .... Please note that per client instructions, we were unable to make it as A wordpress page title, it's a string made using divi builder made to look like a title

Comment: @StephenOstermiller changing now to see if it makes any difference, the client insisted that he wanted  it to be called profile, I said no but he didn't listen, like the majority of clients.

Comment: When you ask for help with your website you shouldn't use scripts that disable right click and view source.   It is much harder to help you with your site when you try to make it harder to inspect the page.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller sorry, the client ask for it too! i never do that. anyhow i disabled it now, will enable it tomorrow. you can do whatever you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Profile" isn't really a bad name for the home page, but it isn't complete.    The home page could be named any of:

- "Brand Name Profile"
- "Profile of Brand Name"
- "example.com Profile"
- "Profile of example.com"

It isn't just the title of the home page that is important though.   The page should have the brand name listed in text on the page.   Most sites have a footer with the brand name.   Right now you don't use the brand name or the domain name anywhere on the page.   I'd suggest adding text to the footer:

> Copyright 2018 Brand Name

The brand name should also be used as the alt tag on the logo.  Your logo currently has `alt=""`.

```
<img src=logo alt="Brand Name">
```

Once the brand name is actually used on the page, then Google will realize that the page is relevant for brand related queries.

Your suggestion of using "home" rather than "profile" won't make much difference.   Text of the brand name and domain name are plenty of signal to Google.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try your suggestions and let you know

Comment: Stephen, can I ask you that do you think using `Copyright 2018 Brand Name` can help ranking for brand name if you has an active trademark or it's rather a plus keyword that makes the page more relevant to that keyword?

Comment: I wouldn't put an extra keyword into your copyright statement.   If you want to rank for a keyword, it makes sense to use it on your page, but probably not in the copyright statement.  There are plenty of other common places that can be optimized for different keywords:  taglines, headings, links, paragraphs.   The important thing is that you use phrases that allow Google to know what your page is about without repeating yourself in ways that seem forced or awkward.